# Clickable link in "Try It" section of some doc pages

Tags: support, documentation

In the "Try It" section of some doc pages, the link is not present.

It is present in the below image[image]

Its not present in the below image[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The routes that don't link require `POST` requests because they create context, so there's nothing meaningful to be gained by going to those URLs in your browser.

The rest of the routes return data when you send `GET` requests to them, which is why the link is useful in that case.

Comment: It would be good if there was some place to debug the request or see the form data being sent. I mean see how good the page looks where we can send `GET` request and sort of debug it.

Comment: [/me/questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-questions) sends `GET` request & doesn't have link. Kindly confirm.

Comment: Looks like it has a link to me?

Comment: OK. Maybe after clicking on **Run**, it gets disabled.